# Update and Replace numerous Fields in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table with 30 columns, I need to find and replace fields in all of the columns. I have the following code, which allows me to do it in a single column:

```
UPDATE Table 
SET Field1 = REPLACE(Field1,'Test','Word') 
WHERE ID <= 3 ;
```

Is there any way to be able to replace throughout all of the columns in the whole table? The table data looks something like this:

```
ID  Field1     Field2     Field3     etc
1   Test 1     Apple 3    Sun 2    
2   Apple 2    Sun 3      Test 2
3   Sun 1      Test 3     Apple 1
```

I want it to look like this:

```
ID  Field1     Field2     Field3     etc
1   Word 1     Apple 3    Sun 2    
2   Apple 2    Sun 3      Word 2
3   Sun 1      Word 3     Apple 1
```

I am using Access 2010

Comment: Did you want to do that by executing one query?  That is possible, but with 30 columns, it would be a monster ... easy to introduce an error and hard to track it down later.  Instead of that, I would use VBA to execute 30 *simple* queries, one for each column replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want. but you can update several field in same query separating by comma `,`

```
UPDATE Table 
SET 
    Field1 = REPLACE(Field1,'Test','Word'),
    Field2 = REPLACE(Field2,'Test','Word'),
    Field3 = REPLACE(Field3,'Test','Word'),
    ...
    Field30 = REPLACE(Field30,'Test','Word'),
WHERE ID <= 3 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments and answers guys, I ended putting the information into excel and using the following VBA code to find and replace all of the information that I needed:

```
Range("A1:AG15").Select
Selection.Replace What:="Test", Replacement:= _
    "Word", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
    SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Again thanks for your help